# How to parse json object in firebase cloud function typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase cloud function in my web application which is mentioned below

```
 saveUserData (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
    const params = req.query.data;
    const typeof(params);

    return res.status(200).send('Inside user data');
}
```

here the typeof(params) is getting as object.

The value of params is

```
{ first_name: 'vij',email: 'vij@gmail.com',mobile_number: '9088888000',address: 'addad,dada'}
```

I want to get the value of mobile number, I have tried params.mobile_number but it's not working.

Comment: Hello, can you show how do you exactly call this Cloud Function?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to access the json using interface

```
  interface userObj {
         first_name: string;
         email: string;
         mobile_number: string;
         address: string;
         city: string;
         gstin: string;
        }
    let obj: userObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.query.data));
    console.log(obj.first_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a comma missing between the value from "mobile_number" and the key "address". Could be that maybe?

If not maybe try params['mobile_number']

Comment: I missed the comma while typing here, Have edited that now.
I tried params['mobile_number'] then I got the error Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"mobile_number"' can't be used to index type 'string | Query | (string | Query)[]'.
  Property 'mobile_number' does not exist on type 'string | Query | (string | Query)[]'.

const params: string | Query | (string | Query)[]

Comment: where are u using params['mobile_number']?

Comment: I tried console.log(params.mobile_number) and console.log(params['mobile_number']), they both are not working,

Comment: Edit your question to show where u are trying to get the value since it doesnt show in your initial question

Comment: So far I've tried to [replicate](https://jsfiddle.net/axpe9oLn/) this, this looks like it is returning a dictionary type, this means this should be able to be accessed as if it was a [dictionary](https://www.poftut.com/how-create-and-use-dictionary-in-javascript-tutorial-with-examples/). Is this method showing you the error "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"mobile_number"' can't be..."?